# Implementing IF Condition Within a T-SQL UPDATE Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, conditional-statements

Using T-SQL, I would like to execute an UPDATE statement that will SET columns only if the corresponding variables are defined.

Here's a simple pseudo-tsql example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

---

```
--Declaring vars
@ID int,
@Name nvarchar(20),
@Password nvarchar(10)

--Run the update
UPDATE User
SET
IF LEN(@NAME) > 0
  Name = @Name,
IF LEN(@Password) > 0
  Password = @Password
```

---

From what I can tell by reading how IF conditions work in T-SQL, in order to accomplish the same result as the above pseudo code, I would have to create an UPDATE statement for every IF condition - which is what I'm trying to avoid having to do.

Is it possible to dynamically SET fields/columns based on a condition using only one UPDATE statement? - If so, how?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The [CASE expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

```
UPDATE User
SET
    Name = CASE WHEN LEN(@NAME) > 0 THEN @Name ELSE Name END,
    Password = CASE WHEN LEN(@Password) > 0 THEN @Password ELSE Password END
WHERE
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be useful:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[CodeUpdate] 
(
    @Id int, 
    @Name nVarChar(150)=null, 
    @IsActive bit =null, 
    @IsSystem bit=null
) AS 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE [dbo].[Code] SET 
        [Name] = CASE WHEN @Name is null THEN [Name] ELSE @Name END,
        [IsActive] = CASE WHEN @IsActive is null THEN [IsActive] ELSE @IsActive END,
        [IsSystem] = CASE WHEN @IsSystem is null THEN [IsSystem] ELSE @IsSystem END
    WHERE  ID = @Id
End
```

Do you like it?
Enjoy.